# Is asking about funny related topics on-topic?

Tags: discussion

Most questions about design and coding patterns are on-topic here, I know, but...

What about questions regarding a funny approach to anti-patterns? In my case I would like to know existent currently in-use funny names for anti-patterns, so it helps students to know and remember what *not* to do in this case (yes, there are cases like the *Diaper Pattern* which still makes me laugh).

Are funny -on purpose- questions -based on a usually accepted topic- on-topic here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do 'some examples' and 'list of things' questions get closed?](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/7537/why-do-some-examples-and-list-of-things-questions-get-closed)

Comment: Possibly relevant: [We hate fun](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/01/stack-overflow-where-we-hate-fun/)  (which concludes that we don't actually hate fun, just mindless questions)

Comment: @DanPichelman you got it :).

Answer (score 5):

Questions like that are probably going to be bad fits anywhere on Stack Exchange, which in general is for serious questions.

I would suggest reddit as that is nearly the exact medium you will find the "best" answers you are looking for.

Answer (score 2):

It a nutshell, what is "funny" is primarily opinion-based by its nature and so would very likely be closed - even if that type of question were to be permitted.